# Type conversion in VHDL: real to integer - Is the rounding mode specified?

Tags: type-conversion, vhdl, xilinx, xilinx-ise, vivado

While debugging the handling of user defined physical types in Vivado ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27792449/can-vivado-handle-user-defined-physical-types)), I found a different behavior for type conversions from real to integer.

Here is my example code:

```
library IEEE;
use     IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
--use     IEEE.MATH_REAL.all;

entity Top_PhysicalTest_Simple is
  port (
    Clock : in STD_LOGIC;
    Input : in STD_LOGIC;
    Output : out STD_LOGIC
  );
end;

architecture top of Top_PhysicalTest_Simple is
  constant int_1     : INTEGER  := natural(0.5);
  constant int_2     : INTEGER  := integer(-0.5);
--  constant int_2     : INTEGER  := natural(-0.5);
begin
  assert FALSE report "16 - int_1 (natural(0.5)):  " & INTEGER'image(int_1) severity note;
  assert FALSE report "17 - int_2 (natural(-0.5)): " & INTEGER'image(int_2) severity note;

  Output <= Input when rising_edge(Clock);
end;
```

*The dummy flip flop is used to prevent some tools from complaining about an empty design.*

**XST 14.7:**

```
Elaborating entity <Top_PhysicalTest_Simple> (architecture <top>) from library <work>.
Note: "16 - int_1 (natural(0.5)):  1"
Note: "17 - int_2 (natural(-0.5)): 0"
```

XST seems to use the mode *round up* and it handles the type conversion inclusive range check.
So I must use `integer(-0.5)` instead of `natural(-0.5)`.

**Vivado 2014.4:**

```
[Synth 8-63] RTL assertion: "16 - int_1 (natural(0.5)):  1" ["D:/Temp/PhysicalTest_Vivado2014.4/vhdl/Top_PhysicalTest_Simple.vhdl":80]
[Synth 8-63] RTL assertion: "17 - int_2 (natural(-0.5)): -1" ["D:/Temp/PhysicalTest_Vivado2014.4/vhdl/Top_PhysicalTest_Simple.vhdl":81]
```

Synth seems to use the mode *round to infinity* and it handles the type conversion without range check. So maybe `natural(..)` is just an alias to `integer(..)`.
The commented line: `constant int_2 : INTEGER := natural(-0.5);` throws no error.

**GHDL 0.29:**

GHDL 0.29 does no range check in `natural(..)`.
I know it's out dated, but since 0.31 hates me I can't tell if this is already fixed.

**GHDL 0.31:**

I'll present the results later. GHDL refuses to analyse my code because:
*Top_PhysicalTest_Simple.vhdl:29:14: file std_logic_1164.v93 has changed and must be reanalysed*

My questions:

- Does VHDL define a rounding mode? And if so which one?
- How should I handle rounding if no mode is defined?

Comment: looks like you managed to install another ghdl version on top of 0.31? A clean install (perhaps to a different location) or "make install" if you built it from source should fix version problems with the standard libraries.

Comment: ghdl-0.32 ...  ./top_physicaltest_simple 
Top_PhysicalTest_Simple.vhd:18:3:@0ms:(assertion note): 16 - int_1 (natural(0.5)):  1
Top_PhysicalTest_Simple.vhd:19:3:@0ms:(assertion note): 17 - int_2 (natural(-0.5)): -1

Comment: Sorry for the mixup: 0.29 was tested on Debian (standard package), 0.31 is my Windows machine (mcode version). Installing and compiling 0.32 is still a task :)

Comment: ghdl -a top_phystest_simple.vhdl (completes).  ghdl --version
GHDL 0.31 (20140108) [Dunoon edition] (on Mac OS X, ask Brian what Dunoon means).  You can also find a download for Debian - http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghdl-updates/files/Builds/ghdl-0.31/Debian/.

Comment: @DavidKoontz The question is what `ghdl -e ...` prints out :) I tried to install ghdl 0.31 on my linux VM but there is a package version missmatch. Debian 8.0 (testing) libgnat-4.9, ghdl requires 4.6, but that's a question for another day ...

Comment: So I reported this different behavior in the [Xilinx forum](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/Type-conversion-in-VHDL-real-to-integer-Different-behavior-in/td-p/557046). Let's see how they justify the different outputs. Moreover, if someone wants to read more on false implemented physical types in Vivado Synth, here is a [second bug report](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/Vivado-Synth-Bug-in-handling-physical-types/td-p/557049)

Comment: ghdl-0.31.`ghdl -r Top_PhysicalTest_Simple - top_phystest_simple.vhdl:18:3:@0ms:(assertion note): 16 - int_1 (natural(0.5)):  1 
top_phystest_simple.vhdl:19:3:@0ms:(assertion note): 17 - int_2 (natural(-0.5)): -1`. Need a flag, re: Phillipe's answer? For natural(-0.5) "If the type mark denotes a subtype, conversion consists of conversion to the target type followed by a check that the result of the conversion belongs to the subtype", "...,and the target subtype of a type conversion is the type or subtype denoted by the type mark", report on ghdl-updates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From IEEE Std 1076-2002 section 7.3.5 "Type conversions"

> ```
> The conversion of a floating point value to an integer type rounds to
> the nearest integer; if the value is halfway between two integers,
> rounding may be up or down.
> ```

If you want something else, maybe functions in `IEEE.MATH_REAL` can be of some use (notably `CEIL`, `FLOOR` and/or `TRUNC`).

Answer (score 0):

( posting this as an answer because I can't post a comment inline... )

Here are the results using the prebuilt ghdl-0.31-mcode-win32 :

```
  C:\brian\jobs\ghdl_test\paebbels>md work.ghd

  C:\brian\jobs\ghdl_test\paebbels>ghdl -a --workdir=work.ghd Top_PhysicalTest_Simple.vhd

  C:\brian\jobs\ghdl_test\paebbels>ghdl -r --workdir=work.ghd Top_PhysicalTest_Simple
  Top_PhysicalTest_Simple.vhd:18:3:@0ms:(assertion note): 16 - int_1 (natural(0.5)):  1
  Top_PhysicalTest_Simple.vhd:19:3:@0ms:(assertion note): 17 - int_2 (natural(-0.5)): -1
```

---

"0.31 is my Windows machine (mcode version)"
"GHDL refuses to analyse my code "

If you're having trouble with libraries on the Windows mcode build of 0.31, try uninstalling any 0.29 or earlier NSIS-installer versions of GHDL on that machine.
Also make sure you ran the through the whole setup process as described in the 0.31 Windows INSTALL, particularly reanalyze_libraries.bat

Here's the version used for the above test:

```
  C:\brian\jobs\ghdl_test\paebbels>ghdl -v
  GHDL 0.31 (20140108) [Dunoon edition] + ghdl-0.31-mcode-win32.patch
  Compiled with GNAT Version: GPL 2013 (20130314)
  mcode code generator
  Written by Tristan Gingold.

  Copyright (C) 2003 - 2014 Tristan Gingold.
  GHDL is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License.  There is NO
  warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

And the library path info :

```
  C:\brian\jobs\ghdl_test\paebbels>ghdl --dispconfig
  command line prefix (--PREFIX): (not set)
  environment prefix (GHDL_PREFIX): C:\Ghdl\ghdl-0.31-mcode-win32\lib
  default prefix: C:\Ghdl\ghdl-0.31-mcode-win32\lib
  actual prefix: C:\Ghdl\ghdl-0.31-mcode-win32\lib
  command_name: C:\Ghdl\ghdl-0.31-mcode-win32\bin\ghdl.exe
  default library pathes:
  C:\Ghdl\ghdl-0.31-mcode-win32\lib\v93\std\
  C:\Ghdl\ghdl-0.31-mcode-win32\lib\v93\ieee\
```